# Cannot Click UIButton When Particle Emitter Is On Screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, particles, emitter

When using a particle emitter, regardless of the position I cannot click the UIButton. If I disable the particle emitter function in viewdidload, I am able to press the UIButton (playButton).

I have tried both zPosition and bringsubviewtofront. I am all out of ideas. Any thoughts?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class HomeMenu: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    
    //multiple emitters = multiple functions!
    //just need to alter positions
    
    //        func bringSubviewToFront(_ view: self.playButton)
    
    particleEmitter()
    
    
    bringButtonToFront()
    
    
}

func bringButtonToFront() {
    self.playButton.bringSubviewToFront(self.playButton)
   
}

func particleEmitter() {
    let sk: SKView = SKView()
    sk.frame = view.bounds
    sk.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.addSubview(sk)

    let scene: SKScene = SKScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    scene.backgroundColor = .clear

    let en = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "SparkParticle.sks")
    //position of emitter on 2d plane
    en?.position = CGPoint(x:50, y:50)

    scene.addChild(en!)
    sk.presentScene(scene)
    //zposition brought emitter to front of view to make visible
    scene.zPosition = 10
}

@IBAction func playButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "startGaneSegue", sender: self)
}


}
```

[In the image, you can see the emitter is located at the bottom left of the screen, but the button is unclickable. Only when removing the emitter is the button clickable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngqCj.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.playButton.bringSubviewToFront(self.playButton)` brings the button to the front of itself (doesn't make sense)! Do this instead:

```
func bringButtonToFront() {
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.playButton)
}
```